# Frequency of the most frequent word using Zipf's law

Tags: statistics

I modeled my corpus using Zipf's law, so that:

$$f_r=c/r$$

Where $f_r$ is the frequency of a word at rank $r$. I calculated $c=90000$.

How can I calculate the frequency and the occurrence for the most frequent word?
Is it as trivial as $f_1=90000$ ?

**update**: for clarification I added that alongside with frequency I am also looking for word occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_r = 90{,}000/r$ would mean the most frequent word occurs $90{,}000$ times, the second one $45{,}000$ times, the third $30{,}000$, and so on.

If you're doing modeling then I would think you have the actual counts so you can see how good a fit this is.  But you haven't given us any of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Almost right, assuming of course that Zipf's law with the basic exponent of 1 applies to your corpus.

But you have to divide by the approximated total of all the frequencies, which if your set contains $N$ words is 
$$T = c \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k} \approx c \ln N.$$

Thus if there are (say) 100000 words, 
$$ f_1 = \frac{90000}{1 \cdot 90000 \ln 100000} \approx 0.0869
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am a bit confused from your answer. Why is my reasoning incorrect? Why do you sum all the 1/k ? And how can the most frequent word appear 0.0869 times? I think my gap of knowledge goes beyond this. I have a feeling I confuse frequency with occurrence. But I still do not understand where you bring the new summation in

Comment: I take to the initial question to mean the most frequent word would occur 90,000 times according to the model, and the second-most-frequent one 45,000 times, the third 30,000, and so on.  Thus dividing by a normalizing constant is not called for. ${}\qquad{}$